# i want to fetch a data from the database

Tags: android

getting the error in the spinner
mainActivity.java file

```
    package com.example.sachin.demodb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Spinner spinner;
    private ArrayList<String> students;
    private JSONArray result;
    private TextView textViewName;
    private TextView textViewCourse;
    private TextView textViewSession;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        students = new ArrayList<String>();
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        //spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewCourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCourse);
        textViewSession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSession);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        //This method will fetch the data from the URL
        getData();
    }

    private void getData() {
        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.example.sachin.demodb.Config.DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        JSONObject j = null;
                        try {
                            //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                            j = new JSONObject(response);

                            //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                            result = j.getJSONArray(com.example.sachin.demodb.Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                            //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                            getStudents(result);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void getStudents(JSONArray j) {
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding the name of the student to array list
                students.add(json.getString(com.example.sachin.demodb.Config.TAG_USERNAME));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students));
    }

    //Method to get student name of a particular position
    private String getName(int position) {
        String name = "";
        try {
            //Getting object of given index
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);

            //Fetching name from that object
            name = json.getString(com.example.sachin.demodb.Config.TAG_NAME);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Returning the name
        return name;
    }

    //Doing the same with this method as we did with getName()
    private String getCourse(int position) {
        String course = "";
        try {
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
            course = json.getString(com.example.sachin.demodb.Config.TAG_COURSE);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return course;
    }

    //Doing the same with this method as we did with getName()
    private String getSession(int position) {
        String session = "";
        try {
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
            session = json.getString(com.example.sachin.demodb.Config.TAG_SESSION);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return session;
    }



        //this method will execute when we pic an item from the spinner
     //   @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Setting the values to textviews for a selected item
            textViewName.setText(getName(position));
            textViewCourse.setText(getCourse(position));
            textViewSession.setText(getSession(position));
        }

        //When no item is selected this method would execute
      //  @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            textViewName.setText("");
            textViewCourse.setText("");
            textViewSession.setText("");
        }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;

    }
}
```

in the following file i getting error on the spinner,

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

here is my config.java file

```
    package com.example.sachin.demodb;

/**
 * Created by sachin on 8/10/2016.
 */
public class Config {
    //JSON URL
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/portal/fetchvisit.php";

    //Tags used in the JSON String
    public static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    public static final String TAG_COURSE = "course";
    public static final String TAG_SESSION = "session";

    //JSON array name
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

and now this is my.xml file..

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.sachin.demodb.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Name"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="Course"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="Session"
                />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/textViewCourse"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/textViewSession"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Getting error like

```
  Error:(50, 43) error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to OnItemSelectedListener
```

pls help me out for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing you activity in `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`, your activity (`MainActivity`) must implement that interface. Therefore, your `MainActivity` definition will look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
        implements OnItemSelectedListener , NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    // Also implement the methods in OnItemSelectedListener interface
}
```

Comment: you're ryt... bt nt getting the data in the spinner

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: @SachinSolanki ideally you should open a different issue for that. But, are you getting any exceptions (since your are catching `JSONException`)? Try to put breakpoints maybe.

Comment: @SachinSolanki Open a different question for this issue as it is quite unrelated to your original query and may not be very helpful to future visitors.

Comment: no worries.. do u have any simple code for fetching a data from the database..???

Answer (score 0):

```
Your Activity is not implementing OnItemSelectedListener interface then you can't pass context to spinner item click listener implement OnItemSelectedListener in MainActivity.

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 
Otherwise, you can pass an anonymous class instance which implements OnItemSelectedListener interface.

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```